# Cannot resolve symbol 'GridLayout'

Tags: grid, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

When I try to program a program in Android Studio, I found this error but I did not know how to resolve it
Cannot resolve symbol 'GridLayout'
this error rises up in Android Studio

I search on internet for solutions
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

import android.widget.GridLayout;